# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd eclipse

Tags: android, interstitial

The interstitialAd showing error of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd

I am using google-play-services_lib and using this code:

```
// Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(yourActivity);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("MY_ID");

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
          public void onAdLoaded(){
               displayInterstitial();
          }
});

 public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }
```

In manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

any solution for this?

my log:

```
03-05 06:56:03.917: E/dalvikvm(1143): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd'
03-05 06:56:35.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd
```

Comment: do have activity with name `InterstitialAd` ... ? if yes .. add it in manifest

Comment: @SukhwantSinghGrewal no. dont have

Comment: @micky Have you managed to find a solution for this issue?